# Hashing, linked list, delete node

Tags: c, list, linked-list

My task is to delete a node from a array of pointers which point to structure.

My code doesn't work and I just don't know why:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Jmena4.h"

#define LENGTH 101
#define P 127
#define Q 31

typedef struct node {
    char *name;
    struct uzel *next;
} NODE;

int hash(const char Name[]) {
    int i;
    int n = strlen(Name);
    int result;

    result = Name[0] * P + Name[1] * Q + Name[n - 1] + n;
    return result % LENGTH;
}

void Insert(NODE *array[], const char *name) {
    NODE *u;
    int h;

    u = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    u->name = name;
    h = hash(name);

    u->next = array[h];
    array[h] = u;
}

int Search(NODE *array[], const char *name) {
    NODE *u;

    u = array[hash(name)];

    while (u != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(u->name, name) == 0) {
            printf("%s\n", u->name);
            return 1;
        }
        u = u->next;
    }
    printf("Name: %s wasn't found\n", name);
    return 0;
}

int Delete(NODE *array[], const char *name) {
    NODE *current;
    NODE *previous;
    int position = hash(name);

    current = array[position];
    previous = NULL;

    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0) {
            if (previous == NULL) {
                array[position] = current->next;
                return 1;
            } else {
                previous->next = current->next;
                current = NULL;
                return 1;
            }
        }
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return 0;
}



int main() {
    int i;
    NODE *array[LENGTH];

    for (i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
        array[i] = NULL;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < Pocet; i++) {
        Insert(array, Jmena[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < PocetZ; i++) {
        Delete(array, JmenaZ[i]);
    }

    Search(array, "Julie");

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT 1: I changed names of variables and instead of `position = array[position]` should be `current = array[position]`, but it still doesn't work.

EDIT 2 : In array Jmena is string "Julie" and I can search it after Insert function, but after I delete strings from JmenaZ which not included "Julie" program output is: Name: Julie wasn't found.

Comment: Add the language tag please.  Also, explain our code please some more.  What do you mean your code doesn't work?  Give us sample input and output.

Comment: What if you tried searching after EACH deletion (as opposed to all of them); will it work after any of them?

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, `current` isn't initialized before it gets tested in the `while` loop.

Comment: I think he meant `current = array[position]`